# Vue JS infinite laoding don't work in v-else

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello i want to add a vue infinite loading in my template in a condition but is don't work

```
<generic-button v-if="!viewMore" inline no-arrow @click="viewMore = true"
            >{{ $t('components.slots.product-list.see-more-favoris') }}
            <template #icon-right>
              <icon-base width="17" height="10">
                <icon-arrow-down color="#ffffff" />
              </icon-base>
            </template>
          </generic-button>
          <infinite-loading
            v-else
            :distance="800"
            force-use-infinite-wrapper
            @infinite="infiniteHandler"
          ></infinite-loading>
<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
      viewMore: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
// function test to infinite loading

    infiniteHandler($state) {
     console.log('hello);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When Iclick to button the infinite don't show i don't understand why please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

i found my problem the condition is good the problem is my css in div parent i add `display:flex` is no good because the infinite loading have a `display` i change css i aad a div parent just  `text-align:center` is good my loading is show thanks